# Find out what a function does

Tags: haskell

```
c a = (a\\).(a\\)
```

I know that `(\\)= foldl (flip delete)` it is standard function.

```
delete x [] = []
delete x (y:ys) = if x == y then ys else y : delete x ys
```

I want to know who i can find out what function `c` does.
What should i do?
If i just focus on `(a\\)` 
delete takes a list and a x that we want to delete from the list.
`(a\\)` already go a list a so we need to send in a value x that we want to delete. `a=[a1,a2,a3]`

```
foldl => (a1 'f' x) 'f' a2) 'f' a3
```

where `f` is `flip delete`.

so from the first element of the a we remove x and from the resulting list we remove sub list a2 and a3. 
so we will get all the values that are unique to a1. It seems like a is a list of lists.
don't know if that is correct.

Comment: start from types always: :) `Prelude Data.List> :t let c a = (a\\).(a\\) in c` ==> `:: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. So it's called as `c xs ys` where both `xs` and `ys` are lists of the same type...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used on lists with unique elements, `(as \\ bs)` is like set difference, i.e. the set of `as` that are not also `bs`. Hence

```
c as bs = as \\ (as \\ bs)
```

Hence it computes the set of `as` that are also `bs`, hence intersection.

Comment: Yes i also noticed it when i tried to run the function but 
i am wonder how can i draw that conclusion without testing it on pc.
it was an old exam question. why does it take two list as argument i mean function c.
Shoudn't it be c xs y delete takes a list and a value(in this case y).

Comment: When you know the type of (\\) it is not hard at all. If not, you need to mentally flip delete and know the type of foldl - then you realize that the "accumulator" is a list (the 2nd arg of delete actually), but since foldl operates on a list, also the other argument must be a list, and the element types are equak (due to use of ==, for example).

Comment: You can see at http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5C%5C that the type of \\ is `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: @Eric The op said it was an old exam question, so I think it is implied that Hoogle is verboten (i.e. no PC!), so I tried to show how to find out under exam conditions.

Comment: @Ingo
f=(flip delete) takes to argument a list and a value.
when we use it with foldl
foldl f shoudn't we need to send a list and a value as argument?
how can i rewrite this without fold so that it becomes clear. what is happening

Comment: @user2975699 not quite since `foldl :: (acc -> e -> acc) -> acc -> [e]` and `flip delete :: [e] -> e -> [e]`, so acc = [e]

Comment: i think i understand that we need to list as argument but still can't see how to rewrite it without fold.
foldl + 0 [1,2,3]=(((1+0)+2)+3)

Comment: How about `filter (flip notElem xs)`

Comment: @ what about it?
type? or something else?
it will take a value x as an argument

Comment: Or, if you want,  `as \\ [b1,b2,b3]` is (((as without b1) without b2 ) without b3)

Comment: @user2975699 You wanted to rewrite (\\\\) without foldl, and I said: How about  `as \\ bs = filter (flip notElem bs) as`

Comment: Yes i see that but what i am wondering is 
 foldl + 0 [1,2,3]=(((1+0)+2)+3) I can do this but can i do something simmilar if i get
foldl (flip delete) [1 ,2, 3] [ 1,2,4]? how can i rewrite whitout foldl?

Comment: @user Let `without = flip delete`. Then `fold without as [a,b,c]` is `(((as without a) without b) without c)` Why must I write everything twice, btw? (Note: think backquotes around the last 3 `without`)

Comment: sry i didn't see this.
this is what i was trying to find out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ingo put two backticks around code with backticks inside it: ``(((as `without` a) `without` b) `without` c)``. :)

Comment: @user2975699 *no*, `foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] = (((0+1)+2)+3)`. Write `-` for `flip delete`, then `foldl (-) [1,2,3] [1,2,4] = (([1,2,3]-1)-2)-4 = ([2,3]-2)-4 = [3]-4 = [3]`.